# Razor cshtml file formatting with CSS :empty pseudoclass

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Razor code:

```
<div class="container">
    @if (Model.firstThings.Any())
    {
        <ul class="firstThings">
            @foreach (var thing in firstThings)
            {
                <li>
                    @thing
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
    @if (Model.secondThing != null)
    {
        <div class="secondThing">
            @Model.secondThing
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

CSS style:

```
div.container:empty:after {
    content: "Please fill this space with either first things or second thing";
    color: darkgrey;
}
```

The issue with this is when there are no `firstThings` or `secondThing` it won't work and show placeholder text.

I've tried to go like

```
<div class="container">@if (Model.firstThings.Any())
    {
        <ul class="firstThings">
            @foreach (var thing in firstThings)
            {
                <li>
                    @thing
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
    @if (Model.secondThing != null)
    {
        <div class="secondThing">
            @Model.secondThing
        </div>
    }</div>
```

It works but it's not an option to go because once we do `format document` command in VS, it all resets to the very first code snippet.

I also thought of using `$.trim()` for container node but it still causes jumping a page for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could approach this a bit differently by using a "empty" class instead of using the `:empty` puesdo selector.

So in your Razor file add something like this:

```
@{
    var cssClass = !Model.firstThings.Any() && Model.secondThing == null ? "empty" : "";
}

<div class="container @cssClass">
```

Then update your css style to:

```
div.container.empty:after {
    content: "Please fill this space with either first things or second thing";
    color: darkgrey;
}
```

If you add anything to the `.container` just call `$('.container.empty').removeClass('empty');` before you add content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some javascript to help with your issue.  Here's one way

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yOCm2b

Note: if there's a comment inside the div, this will not work